# Instagram account verification not working

Tags: instagram, verification, account

I'm trying to register a new app on Instagram. 
However, I'm not getting passed the Account Verification screen. 
I inputted my cellphone number several times, but I'm not receiving an sms with the required code.

Anyone else having this problem or with a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue - am trying to activate using a Hong Kong mobile phone number.  I've entered the full international number but never received an SMS.  My instagram account is no longer functional as any POST request (like, comment etc) prompts for the security code that I haven't been sent.  I've registered a help ticket with Instagram.  Anyone have any thoughts?